# LARAVEL SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

Tags: php, laravel-5

Firstly I used

```
php artisan make:auth
```

Then I change my .env variables like this

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3310
DB_DATABASE=leaflet
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=alpha
```

the i used `php artisan migrate`
It gave me response migration created successfully
Now when I am registering it gives me an error

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
```

Can anyone tell me why?,I checked my database and the tables are created successfully and my mysql server is also running I checked on mysql workbench

Comment: Did you specifically change your MySQL port to `3310` rather than the usual `3306`?

Comment: yes ,coz i have wampp mysql running on port 3306 ! so there was a conflict ,moreover  I can successfully create migrations ,so I think thats nnot an issue

Answer (score 0):

i installed admin for laravel ( install [laravel-admin](https://laravel-admin.org/docs/) and also voyager on another instance)

i try to connect my laravel 5.8 into mysql on xampp.

both cant connect as well (my laravel create tables with php artisan migrate but cant connect)

after that i installed mysql 8  on my system on port 3307

and its worked great with laravel.

if you want please install mysql workbench (instead of phpmyadmin)